# How can I resolve this java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.json.simple.JSONObject error?

Tags: java, json, jersey, rad

I'm developing a Web API in Rational Application Developer using the Jersey framework and Tomcat. I'd like to use JSON, but I'm getting the following error:
[image]

I know this is usually because of a missing jar, so I made sure it was included in my build path:
[image]

And in my includes:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.Request;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
```

(I know they're messy, I'm new to Java.)
If anyone could help me resolve this error or point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Add that jar inside WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, it's already there :(

Comment: That's strange. If the jar was there, then this exception should not raise.

Comment: See if it's checked in the "Order and Export" tab. If not, check it, then refresh the project.