# JSON parsing issue in Android using json simple

Tags: android, json-simple

As i have some issues while working with Android's JSON (i.e. org.json), so here i'm using [json simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/). But when i try to convert string into json object using json parser, such as,

```
JSONObject masterJson = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(stringdata);
```

an error occur :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.json.simple.JSONObject
```

Please suggest a method. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider maybe using prebuilt Java JSON library - json-simple is archived with last update year ago. Have you imported `org.json.JSONArray;`
and `org.json.JSONObject;` ?

Comment: org.json.JSONArray and org.json.JSONObject has some others issues. that's why i started using json-simple. But in android, when i use JSONParser, the error appears.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27504508/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-json-jsonobject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, even if we add the respective jar file, it wont work properly. For adding an external jar file, i followed the steps below:

Right click on project in eclipse -> Buildpath -> Configure Build path -> Java Build Path (left Pane) -> Libraries(Tab) -> Add External Jars -> Select your jar and select ok.

But it didn't work. After googling a lot, i found that, after adding the jar file, select the "Order and Export" tab, then check the currently added external file, finally refresh the project. Then it will work perfectly.

Refer this question: [How can I resolve this java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.json.simple.JSONObject error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30742902/how-can-i-resolve-this-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-json-simple-jsonobjec) In this question, we cant find an answere, but the correct answere was added as a comment. Thanks to [@peeskillet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2587435/peeskillet) for adding the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have missed including the `filename.jar` in your classpath. Include the same and it should get solved.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

If there's problem with import .jar try something else.

Do you use gradle? If yes import in `dependencies` this line: `compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'`

Comment: i use ADT (Eclipse version)